# Authentication Manager throwing NullPointerException in Spring REST Application while creating JWT tokens

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

My REST application is working fine when used basic authentication when i access it through postman.
But i want to get JWT token when i call `/authenticate`

This `try/catch` block

```
try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Invalid username/password");
        }
```

is throwing NullPointerException even when the credentials are right, i am using the same credentials as i was using during Basic Auth.

This is my whole Spring REST configuration.

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-crm-rest-security-solution</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        
        <springsecurity.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        
        <hibernate.version>5.4.22.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.45</mysql.connector.version>
        <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- JSON webtoken support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>spring-crm-rest-security</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Builds a Web Application Archive (WAR) file from the project output 
                and its dependencies. -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JAVA MVC Configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }
    
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        
        return props;               
    }

    
    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        
        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        
        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   
    
}
```

My MVC Initializer

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Security Initializer

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
                        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    // add a reference to our security data source
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;
    
    
    
   @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/customers").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/customers/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/customers").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/customers/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/customers").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/customers/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/customers/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
    }   
    
    //beans
    //bcrypt bean definition
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    //authenticationProvider bean definition
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); //set the custom user details service
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); //set the password encoder - bcrypt
        return auth;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(securityDataSource);
        
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager; 
    }
    
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

My Welcome REST Controller

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.rest;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.AuthRequest;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.util.JwtUtil;

@RestController
public class WelcomeRestController {
    
    private JwtUtil jwtutil;
    
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()); 
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome!!!";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public String generateToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        
        logger.info(authRequest.toString());
        
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Invalid username/password");
        }
        
        return jwtutil.generateToken(authRequest.getUsername());
    }

}
```

The RequestBody has data here as shown in logger (username and password that i pass)

```
logger.info(authRequest.toString());
```

My JWT Util class

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.util;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    private String secret = "javatechie";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, username);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

AuthRequest class

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.entity;


public class AuthRequest {
    
    private String username;
    
    private String password;
    
    
    public AuthRequest() {
        
    }


    public AuthRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthRequest [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

Custom User Service Implementation

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    // need to inject user dao
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findByUserName(String userName) {
        // check the database if the user already exists
        return userDao.findByUserName(userName);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(CrmUser crmUser) {
        User user = new User();
         // assign user details to the user object
        user.setUserName(crmUser.getUserName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(crmUser.getPassword()));
        user.setFirstName(crmUser.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(crmUser.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(crmUser.getEmail());
        
        String[] roleArr = crmUser.getFormRole().split(",");
        
        List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<Role>();
        
        for(String r: roleArr) {
            roleList.add(roleDao.findRoleByName(r));
        }
                        
        Collection<Role> roles = roleList;
        
        user.setRoles(roles);

         // save user in the database
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByUserName(userName);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Oh i didnt used @Autowired annotation (dependency injection)

```
@Autowired
private JwtUtil jwtutil;
    
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```